# Android camera taking landscape picture while on portrait orientation

Tags: java, android, camera, orientation, landscape

I adopted the code from [here](http://adblogcat.com/a-camera-preview-with-a-bounding-box-like-google-goggles/).

Basically, I am adding a bounding box in the middle of the camera to save the portion of the picture. When the camera is in landscape mode, it gets the picture perfectly. I am calling the

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

method and the preview displays in portrait mode and the bounding box is also aligned properly but when the picture is taken, it takes picture of the area 90 degrees to the bounding box.

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where to draw.
    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException exception) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "Exception on Camera.open(): " + exception.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Camera broken, quitting :(",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO: exit program
    }
```

This method takes gets the picture

```
public Bitmap getPic(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    System.gc();
    Bitmap b = null;
    Size s = mParameters.getPreviewSize();

    YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(mBuffer, ImageFormat.NV21, s.width, s.height, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(x, y, width, height), 100, outStream); // make JPG
    b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outStream.toByteArray(), 0, outStream.size()); // decode JPG
    if (b != null) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "getPic() WxH:" + b.getWidth() + "x" + b.getHeight());
    } else {
        //Log.i(TAG, "getPic(): Bitmap is null..");
    }
    yuvimage = null;
    outStream = null;
    System.gc();
    return b;
}
```

And I call it from the camera activity from the button's onClickListener

```
// This method takes the preview image, grabs the rectangular
// part of the image selected by the bounding box and saves it.
// A thread is needed to save the picture so not to hold the UI thread.
private OnClickListener previewListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mAutoFocus){
            mAutoFocus = false;
            //mPreview.setCameraFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
            Wait.oneSec();
            Thread tGetPic = new Thread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Double[] ratio = getRatio();
                    int left = (int) (ratio[1]*(double)mView.getmLeftTopPosX());
                    // 0 is height
                    int top = (int) (ratio[0]*(double)mView.getmLeftTopPosY());
                    int right = (int)(ratio[1]*(double)mView.getmRightBottomPosX());
                    int bottom = (int)(ratio[0]*(double)mView.getmRightBottomPosY());
                    Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    try {
                        savePhoto(mPreview.getPic(left,top,right,bottom));
                        mAutoFocus = true;
                        msg.arg1 = 1;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.w("SAV_JPG",e.getMessage());
                        msg.arg1 = -1;
                    }
                    saveImageHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            });
            tGetPic.start();

        }
        boolean pressed = false;
        if (!mTakePicture.isPressed()){
            pressed = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Any help please.

Thanks,
Noorul

Edited:

Below is the illustration of the scenario. The bounding box area is the part I want to capture. Here is how I calculate the bounds of the bounding box

```
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
    mLeftTopPosY = Math.round(height / 2) - 100;
    mLeftTopPosX = Math.round(width / 2) - 250;
    mRightTopPosY = Math.round(height / 2) - 100;
    mRightTopPosX = Math.round(width / 2) + 250;
    mLeftBottomPosY = Math.round(height / 2) + 100;
    mLeftBottomPosX = Math.round(width / 2) - 250;
    mRightBottomPosY = Math.round(height / 2) + 100;
    mRightBottomPosX = Math.round(width / 2) + 250;

            mCenter = mLeftTopIcon.getMinimumHeight()/2;
    mLeftTopIcon.setBounds((int)mLeftTopPosX, (int)mLeftTopPosY,
            mLeftTopIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()+(int)mLeftTopPosX,
            mLeftTopIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()+(int)mLeftTopPosY);

    mRightTopIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.corners);
    mRightTopIcon.setBounds((int)mRightTopPosX, (int)mRightTopPosY,
            mRightTopIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()+(int)mRightTopPosX,
            mRightTopIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()+(int)mRightTopPosY);

    mLeftBottomIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.corners);
    mLeftBottomIcon.setBounds((int)mLeftBottomPosX, (int)mLeftBottomPosY,
            mLeftBottomIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()+(int)mLeftBottomPosX,
            mLeftBottomIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()+(int)mLeftBottomPosY);

    mRightBottomIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.corners);
    mRightBottomIcon.setBounds((int)mRightBottomPosX, (int)mRightBottomPosY,
            mRightBottomIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()+(int)mRightBottomPosX,
            mRightBottomIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()+(int)mRightBottomPosY);
```

[image: Scenario Illustration]

Comment: have you store this bitamp in file ?

Comment: Pratik, please see illustration, this will not help as the image area taken is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, after taking photo, put below code:

```
File f = new File(filePath);
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

int angle = 0;

if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
angle = 90;
} else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
angle = 180;
} else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
angle = 270;
}

Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postRotate(angle);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;
```